# Unable to connect to the my campus db through omega, the below error keeps popping up

Tags: ssh, cryptography

```
Unable to negotiate with 129.107.56.23 port 22: no matching key exchange method found.
Their offer: Diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,Diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,Diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

Comment: A database on port 22...?

Comment: Read `man ssh-keygen ssh-add ssh`. Your keys, in `~/.ssh/` don't share a key format with the server. Use `ssh -v` to get more information.

Comment: @waltinator This has nothing to do with the user's private key if any and `ssh-keygen` is irrelevant. This is about the **key exchange** algorithm, not about the signature algorithm that is used for authentication nor about the symmetric algorithms used to protect the data. (It is possible however that the server won't support a modern key either, but Pooj hasn't reached that step.)

Comment: @HaukeLaging probably a SSH tunnel.

Answer (score 4):

That server only supports older cryptographic mechanisms. Those mechanisms aren't broken, so it's ok to use them, but they're built on an obsolescent primitive (SHA-1 — broken for some uses, but its weaknesses are not applicable here) and they use finite-field (non-elliptic-curve) Diffie-Hellman, which is much slower than ECDH at the same security level.

According to the [OpenSSH release notes](https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html), OpenSSH 8.2 stopped offering `diffie-hellman-group14-sha1` by default (and the other two had been disabled a while ago, I think in 6.9), but still supports it. You can enable it explicitly in the client configuration file. Put this in [`~/.ssh/config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config):

```
Host omega
HostName 129.107.56.23
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
```

(I left some modern algorithms at the beginning of the list in case the server gets upgraded.)

It's possible that once this part is resolved, you get other errors about other cryptographic algorithms used for the SSH connection. You may need to configure other `XxxAlgorithms` options in `~/.ssh/config`, and if you use a key for authentication you'll probably need to use a key generated with `ssh-keygen -t rsa`.